# Postgres Restrict Users from taking db dump

Tags: postgresql

I have an application where security and data theft are primary concerns. I am using Postgres 9.4 on RDS by AWS.

I have several users who need read permission on the db. I know that these users can essentially write a script to scrape all the data from the db but is there a way to deny them from using the `pg_dump` utility.

I am not sure what code examples I can provide for the same.

Is there any alternate strategy to use here? To share db data with developers without allowing them to take dumps of the same?

Comment: `pg_dump` simply runs `SELECT` statements. And even if you could restrict the usage of `pg_dump` there are plenty of SQL clients that can just export the result of a SELECT statement to (text) file as well. If you give the user the permission to read the data, there is absolutely no way to prevent storing that data locally.

Comment: It looks like you want your users to read *some* data but not the whole. You should probably have a look at fine grained access control and implement table or row level security.